# How to keep all variable name In chisel when generate Verilog code

Tags: chisel

The Register name in chisel can be definitly found in verilog ,.
but Wire name sometimes ellipsis in verilog code.

for example , I cant find `sjwr ,sjwaddr` name in verilog .

```scala
  val sjwr = Wire(Bool()) 
  val sjwaddr = Wire(UInt(jcnt.getWidth.W))
  sjwr    := jcnt_rdy 
  sjwaddr := jcnt
  when (sjwr) { sjBuf(sjwaddr) := sjxv }
```

How can i keep all variable name in chisel when we generate verilog code .
it's important for wave debug.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your interest in Chisel!

There are several reasons why a name may be disappearing.

### Constant Propagation

For many reasons, including interoperability with existing CAD tools, performance, and Verilog debug-ability, Chisel (actually the FIRRTL compiler underneath Chisel) will propagate constants and direct wire connections. For example:

```scala
class MyModule extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })
  val wire = Wire(UInt(8.W))
  wire := io.in
  io.out := wire
}
```

In the above code, `wire` will be removed because it is simply connected to `io.in`, the Verilog will just show:

```verilog
assign io_out = io_in;
```

### Inability to name

Chisel Modules are implemented as Scala Classes. Due to implementation reasons, by default Chisel can only name "top-level" `vals` in the body of the Module, for example:

```scala
class MyModule extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val in2 = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })
  val sum = io.in + io.in2 // this is a top-level val, will be named

  // A method, we can call to help generate code:
  def inc(x: UInt): UInt = {
    val incremented = x + 1.U // We cannot name this, it's inside a method
    incremented
  }

  io.out := inc(sum)
}
```

#### suggestName

You can manually name any signal by calling `.suggestName("name")` on it, eg.

```scala
  def inc(x: UInt): UInt = {
    val incremented = x + 1.U // We cannot name this, it's inside a method
    incremented.suggestName("incremented") // Now it is named!
  }
```

#### Enter @chiselName

**EDIT:** This section applies to Chisel versions before v3.4.0. In v3.4.0 Chisel added a Scala compiler plugin to do much better naming so `@chiselName` is no longer necessary. See the website for documentation: https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/explanations/naming.html

We can fix the above issue with an experimental feature called `@chiselName` like so:

```scala
import chisel3.experimental.chiselName

@chiselName
class MyModule extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val in2 = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })
  val sum = io.in + io.in2 // this is a top-level val, will be named

  // A method, we can call to help generate code:
  def inc(x: UInt): UInt = {
    val incremented = x + 1.U // We cannot name this, it's inside a method
    incremented
  }

  io.out := inc(sum)
}
```

`@chiselName` is an *annotation* that can be used on any `class` or `object` definition and will ensure vals like `incremented` can get named. `@chiselName` effectively rewrites your code to put `.suggestName` all over the place.

I hope this helps!

### EDIT more info:

#### Disabling Optimizations

I don't think it's in a release yet (most recent being `3.1.7`, this will be in `3.2.0`), but we do have an option to disable all optimizations. You can change the "compiler" used from `verilog` to `mverilog` (for "minimum" Verilog, ie. no optimizations). This can be done with the command-line argument `-X mverilog` either in Chisel or FIRRTL.

#### Don't Touch

You can also use `chisel3.dontTouch` to mark a signal as something that shouldn't be deleted. This will prevent optimizations from removing the signal. For example:

```scala
import chisel3.dontTouch
class MyModule extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })
  val wire = dontTouch(Wire(UInt(8.W)))
  wire := io.in
  io.out := wire
```

**EDIT 2**: I've updated for Chisel 3.2 where `dontTouch` moved from package `chisel3.experimental` to the regular `chisel3` package

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answers。the method of suggestName and chiselName are very useful. 

My problems is more about that the name removed in direct wire connections. I know keep Intermediate wire is no practical meaning, but it's useful when wave debug , sometimes i named it just want clear or easy to found it in wave. Does it have some option to close propergate when generate verilog code . After debugging and stabilization, then open propagate option to get the final verilog code (Formal equivalence).

Comment: I've edited my response to talk about how to disable optimizations (not in the current release, you can wait for `3.2` which should be out in a couple of weeks or build Chisel manually from master and use that). I should caution that running formal equivalence tools tend to struggle comparing large designs with and without optimizations, but you can try it.

For specific signals, `dontTouch` can help with what you want.