# How to keep val names under withClock() or withClockAndReset() scopes

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

Val names under `withClock()` & `withClockAndReset()` scopes tend to lose their coded names in the generated Verilog file.

So far in order to maintain to original names I used `suggestName()` function to force the original name.

However I wonder if there is a smarter way do it ? is there a way to force all vals to keep their names without adding `suggestName()` to each val declaration ?

Comment: Does `@chiselName` help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403155/1308473

Comment: Thanks Kamyar, I somehow managed to miss that  post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kamyar mentioned in his comment, you should use the `@chiselName` macro

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.experimental.chiselName

@chiselName
class MyModule extends Module {
  ...
  withClock(otherClock) {
    val importantReg = Reg(...) // <- this will now get a name
  }
}
```

The way `@chiselName` works is it will automatically add a `.suggestName` to each `val`.

Comment: Thanks Jack Koenig for you answer , I tried your suggestion adding the @chiselName I now get the next compilation error: `macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for
that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another
possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same
compilation run that defines it)
[error] class Sha1(srcId: Int) (implicit p: Parameters) extends MultiIOModule { ... ` what am I doing wrong

Comment: Okay, I've figured it out. I updated My build.sbt with the one on the rocketchip github. It has a line that adds the plugin.